# Shell Scripting 101

Tags: linux

Here is my assignment for class: I know you don't post specific questions, but here's what I have tried and it isn't working. I was hoping for someone to point me in the direction and I can go from there:

Write a shell script that performs the following functions:
as the first command in your shell script use the script -a ch10-q1.txt  command.
use the echo command to display the hostname, logname, and home system  variables.
displays the current date and time using Coordinated Universal Time.
displays the list of directories in the user's home directory and all the subdirectories below (hint: use the tree command with the appropriate option).
list all the files in the user's home directory and all the subdirectories below (hint: check the options). Also use the -gF options.
use the df  command to display the space usage in your system. Use the option(s) to include the total size in human readable format.
Save your shell script file in your home directory and name it ch10-1

Here is my code in vi ch10-1.

```
# !/bin/bash
script -a ch10-q1.txt
echo $hostname
echo $date -u
echo $ls -d */u
echo $ls -la
echo $ls gf
echo $df; df -h
```

Then I save the file and make the file executable by:

```
chmod 777 ch10-1
```

I try and run the program by:

```
./ch10-1
```

And then it tells me that line 2-8 command not found.

I guess my questions is how do I have multiple commands?

Comment: Please put your code in codeblocks

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't directly edit your question

Comment: break things down a bit: does `echo $hostname` do what you expect it to do at the command line?

Answer (score -3):

$hostname

The command to display the hostname.